# Generate HMAC Signature on PHP

Tags: php, sha256, hmac

how do you apply the system below to php?

```
StringToSign = HTTPMethod+":"+RelativeUrl+":"+AccessToken+":"+
Lowercase(HexEncode(SHA-256(RequestBody)))+":"+Timestamp

Signature = HMAC-SHA256(apiSecret, StringToSign)
```

my script :

```
$encoderData = json_encode($bodyToHash, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$hash        = hash("sha256", $encoderData);
$stringToSign   = $Method. ":" .$url . ":" . $auth_token . ":" . $hash . ":" . $Timestamp;
$auth_signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $secret_key, $stringToSign,false);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php, the rest looks relatively obvious, what have you tried?

Comment: how to do this system "Lowercase(HexEncode(SHA-256(RequestBody)))"

Comment: `strtolower(bin2hex(hash("sha256", $encoderData)))` maybe

Comment: Did you get the correct answer for Lowercase(HexEncode(SHA-256(RequestBody))) ? @Azivans

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean but
You can try this;

```
<?php
    $stringToSign = 'abcd';
    $apiSecret = 'secretkey';

    $hashed = hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $apiSecret);
?>
```

Comment: We must get the "StringToSign" result
I don't understand in the section "Lowercase (HexEncode (SHA-256 (RequestBody)))" how do I apply it to php

Answer (score 0):

doing some BCA stuff? :p

you can use this function if you wan to use `GET`:

```
strtolower(hash('sha256', ''));
```

Comment: can you share full script to get signature? Thanks